# handling false positives regex

Tags: regex

I have a regex responsible for matching tracking numbers for USPS. There are 2 expressions grouped together as follows:

```
r'\b(9[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{2}|9[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{2} ?[a-z]{2} ?[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{3} ?US)\b'
```

This is an example of what I am trying to match is:

```
9270 1000 0000 0000 0000 00 EA 000 000 000 US
```

while clearly the first part of the string is matching the first expression, it should really match the second expression because that is the right format. The first pattern matches because half of the string satisfies the pattern.

What is the best scenario for handling these types of 'false positives' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that `[0-9]` simplifies to `\d` in most situations - it's a lot easier to read and write.

When you want to alternate between two patterns, and the shorter one *exactly matches* the other up to the end of the shorter one, you might put the longer one first. That is, instead of:

```
\b(
  9\d{3} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{2}
  |
  9\d{3} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{2} ?[a-z]{2} ?\d{3} ?\d{3} ?\d{3} ?US
)\b
```

(leading whitespace and newlines are just for grouping clarity)

you could do

```
\b(
  9\d{3} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{2} ?[a-z]{2} ?\d{3} ?\d{3} ?\d{3} ?US
  |
  9\d{3} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{2}
)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/8CVhJ2/1

But there's a better option: why not match the shorter part *regardless*, and then *optionally* match the remaining part of the longer pattern:

```
\b
9\d{3} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{4} ?\d{2}
(?: ?[a-z]{2} ?\d{3} ?\d{3} ?\d{3} ?US)?
\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/8CVhJ2/2

You can also simplify the above by repeating the sequential subpatterns `\d{4} ?` in a group:

```
\b
9\d{3} ?(?:\d{4} ?){4}\d{2}
(?: ?[a-z]{2} ?(?:\d{3} ?){3}US)?
\b
```

all in one line:

```
\b9\d{3} ?(?:\d{4} ?){4}\d{2}(?: ?[a-z]{2} ?(?:\d{3} ?){3}US)?\b
```